# What is the alternative for event.fixHooks as it is not supported in jQuery 3.5.1

Tags: jquery

I was trying to update jQuery in the application from 1.11.1 to 3.5.1. I noticed that many things broke one of them was event.fixHooks not working with jQuery 3.5.1

```
var dragEvents = [
'dragstart',
'drag',
'dragover',
'drop'
];

enumerable_utils.forEach(dragEvents, function (event name) {
    jQuery.event.fixHooks[eventName] = {
     Props: ['dataTransfer']
};
});
```

Comment: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-jquery-event-props-and-jquery-event-fixhooks-removed

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález in the jQuery upgrade guide it is given that jQuery.event.props and jQuery.event.fixHooks removed but there is no work around/alternative found for fixhooks in jQuery 3.5.1